# Actionscript 3 - Error #1065: Variable ArenaMain is not defined

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have the following code:

```
package com.urbansquall.preloader 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;

    public class Preloader extends MovieClip
    {
     private var m_firstFrame:Boolean = true;

     public function Preloader()
     {
         addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
         return;
     }// end function

     protected function endLoading() : void
     {
         return;
     }// end function

     protected function updateLoading(param1:Number) : void
     {
         return;
     }// end function

     private function checkFrame(event:Event) : void
     {
         if (currentFrame == totalFrames)
         {
             removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
             startup();
             return;
         }
         if (m_firstFrame)
         {
             beginLoading();
             m_firstFrame = false;
             return;
         }
         var _loc_2:* = root.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded / root.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
         updateLoading(_loc_2);
         return;
     }// end function

     protected function get mainClassName() : String
     {
         return "Main";
     }// end function

     protected function beginLoading() : void
     {
         return;
     }// end function

     private function startup() : void
     {
         stop();
         if (!m_firstFrame)
         {
             endLoading();
         }
         var _loc_1:* = getDefinitionByName(mainClassName) as Class;
         if (_loc_1 == null)
         {
             throw new Error("Preloader:startup. There was no class matching [" + mainClassName + "]. You may need to override Preloader::mainClassName");
         }
         var _loc_2:* = new _loc_1 as DisplayObject;
         if (_loc_2 == null)
         {
             throw new Error("Preloader::startup. [" + mainClassName + "] needs to inherit from Sprite or MovieClip.");
         }
         addChildAt(_loc_2, 0);
         return;
     }// end function
    } 
}
```

But when i press enter & ctrl buttons to test it, it shows the error which is shown in title of this topic/thread.

This exact error:

> ```
>     ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ArenaMain is not defined.
>       at global/flash.utils::getDefinitionByName()
>       at com.urbansquall.preloader::Preloader/startup()
>       at com.urbansquall.preloader::Preloader/checkFrame()
> ```

How do I can solve/fix this?

I'm using Adobe Flash Professional CS6.

Comment: 1. The provided code snippet is a piece of **decompiled** code. While it's not a crime to ask such a question, yet the number of **valid** reasons to work with the decompiled code is quite limited, so these questions are generally not loved just for being them. Also, decompiled code is a pain to work with even if it isn't obfuscated. 2. Anyway, there's not helping with this very piece of code because it fails at getting a class definition by the class name, which refers to something that is not even on the provided code. That's the problem with decompilation - it breaks things far too often.

Comment: Try `getDefinitionByName( mainClassName() )`. Also, do you have a variable 
 or class name of `Arena`?

Comment: @ Organis & VC.One : Since this is a decompiled code, and the game was made in a time where only CS3 or earlier was avaliable, so, as i searched, some stuff changed, which 'broke' this game's code in some ways.

This is the game's main code, so, how do i define this ArenaMain variable?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't define it. It's (from what I perceive) a class definition that should be there in the current **ApplicationDomain** for the **getDefinitionByName(...)** method to obtain. What is it and what it is expected to do - only the original developer could answer these questions.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot find the class ArenaMain. This could be due to several reasons so there cannot be a precise answer. I.e.: there might be a MovieClip with definition name of ArenaMain in library which is not marked to be exported in first frame.
Also, you might want to flag "Permit Debugging" in publish settings, which will tell you the complete error stack with line number.